# Obtain folders inside subdirectories

Tags: python, directory

Is there a way to obtain folders inside a subfolder given only the path of the `src` directory in python.
My folder structure :

```
src
  -abc
    -def
    -fgh
  -bcd
    -mno
    -lmj
```

I need to get only `def,fgh,mno,lmj` .Given the path of `src`

Comment: Tell me if the below answer works.

Answer (score 0):

To get the immediate child directories you can use:

```
next(os.walk('.'))[1]
```

Try this :

```
import os

main_path = "./"

subfolders_list = []

folders_in_main_path = next(os.walk('.'))[1]

for fol in folders_in_main_path:
    subfolders_list.extend(next(os.walk(os.path.abspath(fol)))[1])

print(subfolders_list)
```

There are several other ways this ca be done, like using `os.listdir` and `os.path.isdir` and several other ways.